# How to change SHA -1 Certificate Fingerprint Ionic/Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I want to update app SHA - 1 certificate fingerprint. I am using Ionic/Cordova so can anyone tell me how to do that and did I also need to change SHA-256 certificate fingerprint and MD5 certificate fingerprint in order to upload app on 'Google Playstore'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must to generate keystore.

Generate Keystores
To generate keystores for signing Android apps at the command line, use:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

A debug keystore that is used to sign an Android app during development needs a specific alias and password combination as dictated by Google. To create a debug keystore, use:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And after in your Gradle folder run next command [\gradle-6.9.1\bin] (shift + right mouse click - select PowerShell) ->

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```